# Is there a way to limit WooCommerce wc_get_orders to only query certain orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce

I am in the process of converting some code over to support the new WooCommerce HPOS.
The old query is as follows:

```
$orders = get_posts(
    array(
        'post__in'    => $order_ids,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'fields'      => 'ids',
        'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'post_status' => $statuses,
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_my_meta_key',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Here's the updated query. The problem is I can't find a replacement for the `post__in` option. I know `wc_get_orders` has an `exclude` option for excluding certain orders but I cannot seem to find an "include" option.

```
$orders = wc_get_orders(
    array(
        '???????'    => $order_ids,
        'limit'      => -1,
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'return'     => 'ids',
        'type'       => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'status'     => $statuses,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_my_meta_key',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

I tried using "post__in" but it didn't work. I also tried using "include" (since there's an `exclude`) but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add support for custom query variables in [wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support).
To do this you need to filter the generated query.

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query',
    function ( $query, $query_vars ) {
        if ( ! empty( $query_vars['custom_meta_query'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $query_vars['custom_meta_query'] as $meta_querys ) {
                foreach ( $meta_querys as $key => $value ) {
                    $meta_query[ $key ] = $value;
                }

                if ( ! empty( $meta_query ) ) {
                    $query['meta_query'][] = $meta_query;
                }
            }
        }

        return $query;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Now the `wc_get_orders()` can be called like the below code. You can use the `post__in` in the function.

```
$order_ids = array(51060, 51071); // Replace with your desired order IDs
$orders = wc_get_orders(
    array(
        'post__in'    => $order_ids,
        'limit'      => -1,
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'return'     => 'ids',
        'type'       => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'status'     => $statuses,
        'custom_meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_my_meta_key',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

**Tested OK with WooCommerce 6.8**